# Problema con el "Range" y las celdas dobles

Tags: excel, vba

Hola tengo esto en mi excel aqui pongo el rango de celdas que no pueden estar en blanco para ejecutar la macro

```
Range("B9:AE10,B11:AC13,AD12:AD13,AE11:AE16,W17,B17,N14,B15:AD15,I16:J16")
```

pero el problema es que mi excel tiene celdas dobles [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
por ejemplo la primera celda de la imagen es la B11 pero al ser doble ocupa el espacio de la C11 entonces el range detecta que C11 esta en blanco y no ejecuta la macro alguna idea? Por favor

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Al ser celdas combinadas (malísima idea en Excel), tendrás que mirar todas y cada una de las celdas que componen la combinación. En tu caso, tendrías que mirar tanto B11 como C11

Comment: entonces básicamente tengo que poner las celdas combinadas una por una en la formula?

Comment: Debido a que has usado celdas combinadas,me temo que sí, tendrás que comprobar todas y cada una de las celdas. Como no has puesto código ni que estás intentando hacer, no podemos ayudar más. Quizás un bucle, pero no sabemos ni qué quieres hacer, ni como es tu input ni que output esperas ni qué has intentado.